# Always save a constant to a SQL Server field

Tags: sql-server, null

Is it possible to force a field to always be a certain value?

We have a website in production that writes a value entered by the user into a string field.  Now, our requirements have changed and we no longer actually want to save this value.  For technical reasons, we don't want to do a new publish just for this if we don't have to.

What would be ideal is to ALTER the table in such a way that the field will always be NULL and that existing INSERTS and UPDATES into the field will work as normal but SQL Server will NULL the field regardless.

This is a temporary thing.  We will eventually change the code to not write this value.

Just looking for a quick way to NULL the field without changing code, republishing etc...

Is this possible?  Is writing a trigger the only solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why must it be `NULL` now, why don't you just ignore the field then when you're ready to deploy the new code, remove the column?

Comment: For legal reasons.  We have cleared all values for this field and no longer want to save it.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` after trigger that will `NULL` the field each time it is updated / inserted into.

This is the quickest and easiest solution.

Comment: I thought that might be the prevailing solution.  THanks.